# real time update with SQS in Flask

Tags: ajax, flask, amazon-sqs

I have a python script with reads data from an external API, formats it and pushes to dynamoDB for storage and to SQS.

I have a Flask web application. I want this Flask application to read the messages from SQS and update the main page in real time without page refreshes.

Do I need to use another service like Celery to achieve this? People talk about web sockets or AJAX? Does anyone have a simple example?

There is also this service called Pusher which handles it for you apparently?

Update: I managed to get it to work with pusher but it's really slow

Thank you!

Comment: You can post an answer to your own question and accept it. So other people can use your findings as well ;)

Answer (score 1):

I was able to solve the problem with the service called pusher

It basically takes care of the websockets for you. Very easy to use.

Hope this helps anyone who experiences the same problem